# Mac App crashes in review due to iCloud, but iCloud cannot be tested locally. What can I do?

Tags: macos, crash, xcode5, mac-app-store

I have submitted new version of my app for review for the Mac App Store. The update was rejected because it crashed.

The crash happens when the app disconnects from iCloud. This leads to a strange problem:

The app supports storing files in iCloud and thus includes the iCloud entitlement. An app which uses iCloud and which is signed with a Mac App Store Distribution Profile cannot be launched, because only apps loaded from the App Store are allowed to use iCloud.

Thus I am not able to test the version I submitted on my machine. I can compile an run the app without signing it with a Mac App Store Distribution Profile, but then I cannot use/test iCloud.

I got the CrashLog from the review but I have no idea what the problem might be. Does any one has an idea how to handle this?

```
Process:         MyApp [69811]
Path:            /Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp
Identifier:      com.example.MyApp
Version:         1.2 (1.2)
App Item ID:     0
App External ID: 0
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [184]
Responsible:     MyApp [69811]
User ID:         201

Date/Time:       2014-01-29 13:20:22.910 -0800
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.1 (13B42)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  FE66701D-3E78-131A-A6CA-844122FA6616

Sleep/Wake UUID: DF88CF2B-42D1-40BD-BAC7-4C433EC11A34

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9266ea52 __semwait_signal_nocancel + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8ca39a7c nanosleep$NOCANCEL + 189
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8ca635fe usleep$NOCANCEL + 54
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8ca8fbc4 abort + 135
4   coop.plausible.CrashReporter    0x000000010343030e uncaught_exception_handler + 27
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8bc0f8c2 __handleUncaughtException + 706
6   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff8a805304 _objc_terminate() + 94
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff8e6623e1 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 8
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff8e662456 std::terminate() + 54
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff8a8050b0 objc_terminate + 9
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff91e912c1 _dispatch_client_callout + 28
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff91e98f03 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 333
12  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8bb76839 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
13  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8bb31b14 __CFRunLoopRun + 1636
14  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8bb31275 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
15  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff93622f0d RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 226
16  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff93622cb7 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 479
17  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff93622abc _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 65
18  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff875e928e _DPSNextEvent + 1434
19  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff875e88db -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 122
20  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff875dc9cc -[NSApplication run] + 553
21  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff875c7803 NSApplicationMain + 940
22  com.example.MyApp   0x0000000102f92242 0x102f89000 + 37442
23  com.example.MyApp   0x0000000102f8adb4 0x102f89000 + 7604
```

Comment: And they provided no details of the exception thrown?

Comment: They provided a screenshot which button was clicked before the crash and the crash log. The button triggers de-connection from iCloud. This however just releases some resources an I can't see anything that might cause a problem. Thanks to weichsels answer I was able to run the app with iCloud enabled. But still cannot reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* test iCloud enabled apps on your machine during development.
iCloud does require entitlements, signing and provisioning but it also works with development provisioning profiles.
You can use your developer signing ID for debug builds.

Xcode 5 also gained an iCloud debug pane that shows some details about your container and current transfers:
[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer. It seems it was some kind of problem with my Profile. After creating a new Developer Profile I was able to compile and run the App with iCloud enabled! However I can sill not reproduce the issue. Everything works fine here and I have no idea what might have caused the problem in review. I do not have a lot of experience with crash reports. Does any one see some source of the problem?